# How to count blank cells for each group and for each column in R

Tags: r

I have a data set similar like this:

```
Company   var1   var2   var3   var4
A           1             3      3
B           3     5       2      1
A           7     6              7
A                 1       0      2
B
C           3     4       2      4
F           4             1      5
C           7     7       7      7
```

Ultimately I want to generate a table that tells me how many blank cells do I have in each var for each company.
The ideal output would be:

```
Company   var1   var2  var3  var4
A          1      1     1     0
B          1      1     1     1
C          0      0     0     0
F          1      0     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you provide the data in a standard form. Here is a base R solution.

```
df=read.table(text="Company var1 var2 var3 var4 
A 1 NA 3 3 
B 3 5 2 1 
A 7 6 NA 7 
A NA 1 0 2 
B NA NA NA NA
C 3 4 2 4 
F 4 NA 1 5 
C 7 7 7 7",header=T)

> t(sapply(split(df[,-1], df$Company), function(x)colSums(is.na(x))))
  var1 var2 var3 var4
A    1    1    1    0
B    1    1    1    1
C    0    0    0    0
F    0    1    0    0
```

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Company) %>% summarise_at(2:5, funs(sum(is.na(.))))
```

Comment: Thanks @zack for reformatting the data. I posted before that. :)